# Undefined reference to glewInit@0

Tags: c, opengl, linker, glew

I'm using "i686-w64-mingw32" and trying to link to GLEW.

Here is a test main.c I am using:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <gl/glew.h>

int main() {
    glewInit();
    return 0;
}
```

(I know that this is not the correct way to use GLEW since I haven't correctly initialised and binded an OpenGL context - I'm just trying to get GLEW to link correctly and I'll worry about using it correctly later.)

The line I am using to compile is:

```
gcc main.c -o bin.exe -lglew32s -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

However I receive this error:

```
main.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `glewInit@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Couldn't find a fix from that link. I appear to have linked in the correct order, and I'm not at all associated with C++. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. The OP does not want to know what an undefined reference error is, but rather why they are getting one after linking to what seems to be the correct library.

Comment: File names are case sensitive on Linux. The name of the normal GLEW library file is libGLEW.so thus you would link to it with `-lGLEW`. I imagine that that static version (if it exists on Linux, are you sure it does?) would be named similarly.